# Algorithm to pixelate positions and fluxes

Tags: python, image, pixel, particles, astronomy

What would you do if you had n particles on a plane (with positions (x_n,y_n)), with a certain flux flux_n, and you have to pixelate these particles, so you have to go from (x,y) to (pixel_i, pixel_j) space and you have to sum up the flux of the m particles which fall in to every single pixel? Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Personally, I would request a diagram from the person asking me.

Comment: no suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are several ways with which you can solve your problem.

Assumptions: your positions have been stored into two `numpy array` of shape (N, ), i.e. the position `x_n` (or `y_n`) for `n` in `[0, N)`, let's call them `x` and `y`. The flux  is stored into a `numpy array` with the same shape, `fluxes`.

**1 - INTENSIVE CASE**
Create something that looks like a grid:

```
#get minimums and maximums position
mins = int(x.min()), int(y.min())
maxs = int(x.max()), int(y.max())
#actually you can also add and subtract 1 or more unit 
#in order to have a grid larger than the x, y extremes
#something like mins-=epsilon and maxs += epsilon

#create the grid
xx = np.arange(mins[0], maxs[0])
yy = np.arange(mins[1], maxs[1])
```

Now you can perform a double `for loop`, tacking, each time, two consecutive elements of `xx` and `yy`, to do this, you can simple take:

```
x1 = xx[:-1] #excluding the last element
x2 = xx[1:]  #excluding the first element

#the same for y:
y1 = yy[:-1] #excluding the last element
y2 = yy[1:]  #excluding the first element

fluxes_grid = np.zeros((xx.shape[0], yy.shape[0]))
for i, (x1_i, x2_i) in enumerate(zip(x1, x2)):
    for j, (y1_j, y2_j) in enumerate(zip(y1, y2)):
        idx = np.where((x>=x1_i) & (x<x2_i) & (y>=y1_j) & (y<y2_j))[0]
        fluxes_grid[i,j] = np.sum(fluxes[idx])
```

At the end of this loop you have a grid whose elements are pixels representing the sum of fluxes.

**2 - USING A QUANTIZATION ALGORITHM LIKE K-NN**

What happen if you have a lot o points, so many that the loop takes hours?
A faster solution is to use a quantization method, like K Nearest Neighbor, KNN on a rigid grid. There are many way to run a KNN (included already implemented version, e.g. [sklearn KNN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html)). But this is vary efficient if you can take advantage of a GPU. For example this my tensorflow (vs 2.1) implementation. After you have defined a squared grid:

```
_min, maxs = min(mins), max(maxs)
xx = np.arange(_min, _max)
yy = np.arange(_min, _max)
```

You can build the matrix, `grid`, and your position matrix, `X`:
    grid = np.column_stack([xx, yy]) 
    X = np.column_stack([x, y])

then you have to define a matrix euclidean pairwise-distance function:

```
@tf.function
def pairwise_dist(A, B):  
    # squared norms of each row in A and B
    na = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(A), 1)
    nb = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(B), 1)
    # na as a row and nb as a co"lumn vectors
    na = tf.reshape(na, [-1, 1])
    nb = tf.reshape(nb, [1, -1])
    # return pairwise euclidead difference matrix
    D = tf.sqrt(tf.maximum(na - 2*tf.matmul(A, B, False, True) + nb, 0.0))
    return D
```

Thus:

```
#compute the pairwise distances:
D = pairwise_dist(grid, X)
D = D.numpy() #get a numpy matrix from a tf tensor
#D has shape M, N, where M is the number of points in the grid and N the number of positions.
#now take a rank and from this the best K (e.g. 10)
ranks = np.argsort(D, axis=1)[:, :10]
#for each point in the grid you have the nearest ten.
```

Now you have to take the fluxes corresponding to this 10 positions and sum on them.

I had avoid to further specify this second method, I don't know the dimension of your catalogue, if you have or not a GPU or if you want to use such kind of optimization. 
If you want I can improve this explanation, only if you are interested.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer, this is very useful. 
I implemented something similar to your first algorithm. Mine is in C++ and I arranged position on the grid -from Mpc to pixels- but I don't know how to do the final step, i.e. add fluxes, you can help me maybe, but I guess it is very much slow indeed, since my pixel grid is 2068*2068 pixels and particles can be up to 1 M. 
Do you think the second solution you propose could be better for my goals? Thanks.

Comment: Yes I think that if you use tensorflow with gpu, you can solve your problem fastly. I have done something similar in order to extract density maps of globular clusters within a galaxy cluster. I had a problem with similar dimensions and it worked very weel, requiring fee seconds. But you should have an available gpu and install tf. Maybe the better solution is that you try to implement your script version and if you have problem, you should open a new post, specifying the new nature of the problem (in this case append to this post the link and I'll try to help you out).

Comment: Thanks, one more time. I have just opened a specific post about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066196/mapping-particles-on-a-grid-how-to-add-more-features .